# Setting last cell right aligned in a row

Tags: css

I'm setting my div display as table-cell like this.

HTML

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
    <div class="child">3</div>
    <div class="lastchild">4</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.child{
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.lastchild {
    background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 0;            
}

.parent {
    width:200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1p3y93/

I wonder if there's any way I can set the rightmost cell right aligned?

Comment: What do you mean by: "rightmost cell right aligned"?

Comment: For the example I showed above, it's the 4th box.

Answer (score 2):

Change CSS to:

```
.lastchild {
   background: blue;
   width: 20px;
   display: table-cell;
   margin-right: 0;   
   float:right;
}

.child {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: However by adding 'float:right' it will jump to another line

Comment: yes, it looks better. However I've got another problem then. The cells are not with same height. http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1p3y93/2/

Comment: so you want each cell with same height or else.?

Comment: Yes I've put them in table-cell for setting same height. But it now fails again by setting the float :(

Answer (score 0):

Remove `table-cell` property and use `float` property. Update your CSS like below.

```
.child{
background: red;
width: 20px;
float:left;
}

.lastchild {
background: blue;
width: 20px;
margin-right: 0; 
float:right;
}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1p3y93/1/)

Comment: However I've got another problem then. The cells are not with same height. jsfiddle.net/Lx1p3y93/2

Answer (score 0):

How about pseudo elements? [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lx1p3y93/3/)

```
.child{
    background: red;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    float:left;
}

.child:last-child {
    background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 0;          
    float:right;
}

.parent {
    width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For this purpose you can use this piece of code into your `.lastchild` class:

```
.lastchild {
    background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
    margin-right: 0; 
    float: left;           
}
```

This will align the `.lastchild` item to the most right of the `.parent` element